How to Minimize Startup Latency in DASH Livestream (~1.5 seconds)?
I'm working on a low-latency DASH livestream setup where I aim to achieve startup latency close to 1.5 seconds. Here's the current configuration:
Streaming Tool: FFmpeg
Serving Requests: Nginx
UI Player: DASH.js

Below is my FFmpeg command:
ffmpeg -loglevel debug -probesize 32 -analyzeduration 0 -i udp://127.0.0.1:6311?buffer-size=1310172 \
-fflags +nobuffer -flags low_delay -err_detect ignore_err \
-c:v copy -b:v:0 1000k -b:v:1 2000k -c:a copy \
-keyint_min 10 -g 10 -sc_threshold 0 \
-movflags +frag_keyframe+empty_moov+default_base_moof \
-pix_fmt yuv420p -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency \
-use_template 1 -use_timeline 0 -streaming 1 \
-adaptation_sets "id=0,seg_duration=1.0,streams=v id=1,seg_duration=1.0,streams=a" \
-flags +global_header -format_options "movflags=cmaf" \
-live 1 -ldash 1 -write_prft 1 -target_latency 1.0 \
-http_persistent 1 -f dash /path/manifest.mpd

Challenges I'm Facing:
1> Startup Latency: Despite all the optimizations above, my startup time is still slightly higher than the target of ~1.5 seconds.
2> Chunked Transfer Encoding (CTE): FFmpeg writes to .tmp files until the operation is complete. This prevents real-time data from being accessible for streaming. Is there a way to enable chunked transfer encoding (CTE) to mitigate this, especially when using segment durations greater than 1 second?
Questions:
1>  Are there any improvements or adjustments I can make to the FFmpeg command to reduce startup latency further?
2>  How can I enable chunked transfer encoding (CTE) so I can use  larger segment durations (>1 second) without increasing latency

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Welcome to Superuser. Please note that this site requires that each post have only a single answerable, practical, and specific question. You have at least 2 questions here. Please choose one of them and EDIT your question to focus on that. Also, asking if there are "any improvements" tends to be poorly received because that is usually asking for opinion and your "problem" may be based on a wide range of factors you have not taken into account. System specs may play a role, and you haven't included those. Also, have you looked through the ffmpeg arguments to see if they add latency?

1.5 seconds is pretty fast in my opinion. Is it possible to get lower? Maybe. Could improvement require better hardware components? Possibly. What is "slightly higher", specifically?
